# Como ajustar o tamanho do label no bootstrap 4 para adequar ao input pequeno?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

tenho o código abaixo e não sei como ajustar o label para se adequar ao mesmo tamanho setado no elemento input. 
Do jeito que está o Label tem o texto maior que o Input. Já tentei usar a classe .small mas fica menor.
Uso Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm inverted" type="text" id="nome">
</div>
```

Comment: adicione a class na div col-sm-{valor}.. esse valor vai de 1 a 12. sendo 12 a extensão

Comment: Qualquer duvida, veja essa referencia:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Cara não deu para entender bem o que vc precisa, tem como postar uma imagem simples? Vc que um inpute pequeno tipo que caiba apenas 2 ou 3 caracteres é isso? Como assim "input menor que o label" ?

Comment: Pessoal acho que não fui muito claro na pergunta. 
@JoséFrancisco Não se refere a grid system.
Me referi ao tamanho da fonte do label e o tamanho da fonte dentro do input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu testei usando o `Small` no `Label` e funcionou. Pode ser que vc esteja tendo algum problema de *override* de classes com o Bootstrap.

De qualquer forma veja que mesmo com a classe `Small` funcionando o meu problema vai inverter. Com `Small` o texto da `Label` vai ficar Menor que o texto 
`Input`. Veja as imagens para entender melhor (quadrados vermelhos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Então para resolver o problema aconselho colocar um valor direto na classe do `Label` Veja no Exemplo abaixo, Assim fica tudo do mesmo tamanho.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=c ontent=>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <style>
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: .5rem;
            font-size: .875rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm inverted" type="text" id="nome" value="Nome">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Depois de uma pesquisa mais aprofundada na documentação achei uma solução mais simples. use as classes **col-form-label col-form-label-sm**.  (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form-label-sizing)

Comment: Legal, o BS4 tem várias classes novas, dessa eu não sabia. Se puder usar a classe "Nativa" é melhor mesmo, fica a resposta como registro. Mas considere vc mesmo responder sua pergunta com a Solução